# NUnit global SetupFixture not being executed

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0

I am trying to execute some code before all tests - even more specifically - even before all test case sources being evaluated.

The supposed-to-work-solution is not executing the code (breakpoint is being hit after test case sources were evaluated):

```
[SetUpFixture]
public class GlobalSetup
{
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        // Unfortunately does stuff after TestCaseSources
    }
}
```

I managed to achieve this by creating a fake test fixture with static constructor like this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class GlobalSetup
{
    //Step 1
    static GlobalSetup ()
    {
        // Does stuff before every other TestCaseSource
    }

    //Step 3
    [Test, TestCaseSource (nameof (GlobalSetup.TestInitializerTestCaseData))]
    public void Setup () { }

    //Step 2
    public static IEnumerable TestInitializerTestCaseData => new[] { new TestCaseData () };
}
```

What is the correct way to not use this workaround?

Comment: You can read about this in https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/141

Answer (score 0):

As the comments in the issue Pablo notPicasso cited indicate, you are trying to use NUnit in a way it isn't designed to be used. A global setup is possible, of course, but it runs before all other **test execution**. Test case sources are evaluated as a part of **test discovery** which has to be complete before any test execution can begin.

It's usually possible to use a global setup by reducing the amount of work done in your TestCaseSource. This is desirable anyway - TestCaseSource should always be as lightweight as possible.

Your example doesn't indicate exactly what you are trying to do before the tests are loaded. If you add more info, I can refine this answer. Meanwhile, here are a couple of examples...

If your TestCaseSource is creating instances of the objects you are testing **don't do that**. Instead, initialize parameters like strings and ints that will be used in the SetUp or OneTimeSetup for your tests.

If your TestCaseSource is initializing a database **don't do that**. Instead save the parameters that are needed to initialize the database and do it in a OneTimeSetUp at some level in the test hierarchy.

Hopefully, you get the idea... or provide some further info on what you are doing.

The workaround you have selected looks like it would work in the current implementation. However, it depends on the exact, unspecified order in which NUnit does things internally. It could easily stop working in a future release.